# Compare two Pandas dataframes ignoring list order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to test if two dataframes are equivalent. The column 'Loc2' is equivalent in both dataframes, but the order of strings in column 'Loc1' differ.

DF1:

```
Event  Loc1  Loc2
1      A, B  X
2      C     Y, Z
3      D, E  Z, Y
4      E, F  Z
```

DF2:

```
Event  Loc1  Loc2
1      B, A  X
2      E, D  Z, Y
3      C     Y, Z
4      F, G  Z
```

I need to make sure the dataframes are equivalent and test both columns 'Loc1' and 'Loc2', even though 'Loc2' is always identical.

I know I can compare Loc2 using set operators:
`intersect = set(df1.Loc2) ^ set(df2.Loc2)`

and I know I can split the Loc columns into a single list with: `Loc1 = [item.strip(' ') for x in df.Loc1.str.split(',').tolist() for item in x]`, but this doesn't help me as I need the event number of any mismatches

My ideal output would return:

- `NaN` if the datasets match perfectly
- `4  F, G  Z`, the mismatched row in either DF1 or DF2
- OR just `4`, the event number for mismatched rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom function to standardize the strings:

```
import re

def standardize(df):
    return df.applymap(lambda x: ','.join(sorted(re.split(', *', x)))
                       if isinstance(x, str) else x)

out = 
standardize(df1).eq(standardize(df2))
```

Output:

```
   Event   Loc1  Loc2
0   True   True  True
1   True   True  True
2   True   True  True
3   True  False  True
```

Other outputs:

```
np.all(standardize(df1).eq(standardize(df2)))
# False

df1.loc[~out.all(axis=1), 'Event'].to list()
# [4]
```

Comment: the standardize function doesn't appear to modify my dataframes and all the elements are still in the same order. Is there anyway I could split the strings and then order them in each row so that they're consistent in both dataframes?

Comment: @psuedophyla check the latest version, I initially forgot `sorted` ;)

Comment: although the outputs of standardize(df1) and standardize(df2) are exactly equal, `out = 
standardize(df1).eq(standardize(df2))` seems to return an unexpected output of True/False. this occurs in the 'Event' columns, which is just singular integers, as well so I don't suspect its an issue relating to object types

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible constructor that doesn't give the expected output? Works well with your example. Do you have other columns/rows?

Comment: Also do you have consistent types in each column? I used `applymap` for flexibility but `apply` might be better in this case. Again, depends on the exact reproducible data.

Comment: @psuedophyla unfortunately I didn't get the end of your comment. If you want to align on "Event" you probably should `set_index('Event')` on both inputs.

Comment: sorry about that! @mozway 
the issue was due to differences in indexing between the two dataframes, i fixed it by reindexing them as you mentioned. thank you for all of your help :)